# Serving files from BlobStore in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to ask if I can download files from the blobstore in google app engine (zip files especially) without using the handlers(class handlers). I mean serve files directly without downloadhandler class usage.

Have any idea??

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. (if I understand the question properly)  There is no direct URL for blobstore items, so you can't get at them directly.  [However you can serve blobs from URLs that you define with less than 10 lines of code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Complete_Sample_App).

EDIT: [The send_blob also takes a save_as argument.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.html#BlobstoreDownloadHandler)  Try `save_as=True` to use the blob's uploaded filename as the attachment filename.

Comment: :I know that i can use ***class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):***but the problem that i created zip file on the blobstorage and i got the blobkey for that file but i can't serve it using this approach,please have any idea??

Comment: Why can't you serve it using this approach?

Comment: @mjhm:i know this parameter(save_as)and i tried it in upload and download(serve)from the blob,and it's worked correctly,but the problem exactly i uploaded zip file to the blob and it's uploaded successfully and i can get the blobkey for this file but when serve this file using he download handler i can't pass this key to this handler,and that is the problem.Thanks for your help.

Comment: send_blob takes a BlobInfo object, not a BlobKey.  Maybe you need something like .send_blob(BlobInfo.get(your_blob_key)).

Comment: @mjhm:I understand these ideas,i created zip on the blob store successfuly but i can't use download handler to serve this file,i got the BlobKey and BlobInfo for this file but when i try to call ServeHandler and pass this info to it,i got this problem :((Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0)).Have any idea for this problem?Thank you.